# Capturing value which may or may not exist

Tags: java, regex, groovy

I have multiple lines as follows where 'ProgressiveAwardWinnings' portion may or may not exist. I am trying to extract the number data from these lines.

> LineStake":5000.0,"Won":200, -something-
>   ProgressiveAwardWinnings":10000 LineStake":5000.0,"Won":100,
>   -something-

Thus the extracted information from first line will be 5000.0, 200, 10000 and second line will be 5000.0, 200, null.

My regex is as follows. The 3rd value shows as null for both lines. I am expecting the 3rd value to be captured for line 1. Please advice.

Regex

```
LineStake\":([0-9\.]+),\"Won\":([0-9\.]+),.*?(?:ProgressiveAwardWinnings\"\:([0-9]+))?
```

Comment: @AxelH, the `(?:)` is a non-capturing group, the colon is not a literal. And the first `?` belongs to the `*` quantifier, making it non-greedy.

Comment: @MalteHartwig didn't knew that one, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the **lazy** `.*?` matches 0+ chars as *few* as possible, and is skipped the first time the regex engine comes up to that pattern part, and tries to match the rest of the patterns. If they match, the `.*?` is not even tried, is not *expanded*. The `(?:...)?` non-capturing group is optional, it can match an empty string.

So, once `200` is matched on line 1, `.*?` is skipped and `(?:...)?` matches an empty space after `200`, and the match is returned at that point.

The solution is to put `.*?` into the optional group:

```
LineStake\":([0-9\.]+),\"Won\":([0-9\.]+),(?:.*?ProgressiveAwardWinnings\"\:([0-9]+))?
                                             ^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ehv1xr/1)

Comment: Forgot to add: adding the `.*?` into the `(?:...)?` works, because `?` is a *greedy* quantifier, so the regex engine will attempt to match its pattern at least once.